# How to select data from parent table that don't associated with foreign key in child one

Tags: mysql, sql, select

There are two tables (Person and Car) associated with each other by a foreign key in the child table. The Person table can have repeating person's names. I need to select all the unique names from Person that don't have any cars associated with them. In other words, I must check what persons don't have any cars and select them.

Comment: Hint:  `NOT EXISTS`.  or `NOT IN`.  or `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM   person p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   car c
                   WHERE  p.id = c.owner_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the many possible queries.

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM person p LEFT OUTER JOIN car c 
     ON p.id = c.id
WHERE c.id is NULL;
```